# Web Dev Middleware auto reloading

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to auto-reload (no hot-reloading) some JavaScript through webpack-dev-middleware.

Current code for my Express server:

```js
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    inline: true,
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {colors: true}
}));
```

Everything seems to run fine, but when I change something, my browser doesn't auto reload (although webpack rebuilds...).

Do I need to add an extra entry to auto-reload the browser with webpack-dev-middleware?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like webpack-dev-middleware does not support auto-reload. The way to go instead is to start your express server on a different port and start a webpack-dev-server with [`contentBase`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base) pointing to your express server (or using [`proxy`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) for more fine control). (See [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/8).)

Another way is to do it the other way round and to [start a dev-server programmatically](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api) and modify its internal express server:

```js
var server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), webpackDevServerConfig);
server.app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // server.app is an express server
});
server.listen(8080, "localhost", function(err) {
});
```

Answer (score -1):

@cdauth has almost got it with his second example, but that's not the right way to modify the internal server. The right way is to put a `setup` function in your webpack-dev-server config:

```js
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
    // Your configuration here
    setup(app) {
        // Modify express app here, e.g.
        app.get('/rest/my-path', myModule.myFunction);
        app.use(...);
    },
    // or, instead, you could put your configuration in another module:
    setup: someModule.configureApp, // function that accepts an Express app
});
```

This is way easier than trying to run your server and webpack-dev-server at the same time. You can keep your original configuration using plain Express and use that as an entry point for testing and production, but put the above code in a new file (say `devServer.js`) and use that for development.